# How to set ChannelData for Facebook when using FormBuilder?

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger

I can add ChannalData to messages if I send normal messages:

```
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.ChannelData = JObject.Parse("{'messaging_type':'RESPONSE'}");
```

But if I am using the FormBuilder,

```
return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
    .Message("Welcome to the sandwich order bot!")
    .
    ...
.Build();
```

I don't know how to add the ChannelData.

The following info was found on the Facebook dev documentation and is the reason I why I ask.

> Breaking Change Notice
>   Beginning May 7, 2018 the messaging_type property will be required and all messages sent without it will not be delivered.

Comment: If the purpose of your question is only to manage this breaking change notice, I'm sure that it is necessary as it may be managed by the Bot Connector like many other features it is already doing, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know. But i will try the answer from "shawkyz1" to be sure that it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by implementing it in the **OnCompletion** delegate. Which is triggered when the form is completed.

```
    return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
        .Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
        .OnCompletion((context, state) => context.Activity.ChannelData = JObject.Parse("{'messaging_type':'RESPONSE'}"))
        .Build();
```

Comment: I have just seen that this doesn't do it. The Message() function is already sent to the Client, after that the OnCompletation() function will be called.

Comment: you're right, That's already too late since you'll need to send in the very beginning. I'll have a look at it again

Comment: I've a question though.. Do you have to set it inside the Dialog? can't you set it before redirecting to it?

Comment: I tried already but was not able to get it to work, because there are already information inside the ChannelData. But I will try once more.

Comment: I tried this in the beginning. But this will be replaced inside the FormBuilder. var form = new FormDialog<ProfileForm>(new ProfileForm(), ProfileForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                JObject cd = context.Activity.ChannelData;
                cd.Add(new JProperty("messaging_type", "RESPONSE"));
                context.Activity.ChannelData = cd;
                context.Call(form, ResumeAfterNameForm);

Comment: Yea I noticed that too when I tried it out yesterday. I will check the github repo. If it wasn't there I will send a PR and write the link here in a comment.